# How does the selection process for jury duty work?

Tags: united-kingdom, jury

I've recently received a jury summons and since this is all very new to me I've spoken to a number of people I know, it turns out no one I've spoken to has ever been summoned, leading me to believe it's relatively uncommon. Yet less than a week later, my partner also received a summons to a separate case in a different court.

We're not legally connected (not married or currently living together), the only similarity visible to the government that I can think of is our ages (mid 20's).

Is this just the product of bizarre chance, or does the selection process (UK) involve anything that might cause this?

Answer (score 1):

You were selected because you are registered on your local government’s electoral register. They can tell you the process, i.e. if you and your partner are new voters or new residents in the area, that's why you were both selected. I wouldn't worry about this being a bizarre chance. You must complete and return the form within 7 days.

Your options are: do jury service, opt out or be fined. See https://www.gov.uk/jury-service/overview

Comment: That's how random selection works. Coincidence should be expected.

Comment: It's a conspiracy; they're out to get you and make you do jury duty. Wear your tin foil hat and they will not select you.

Comment: I understand the concept of randomness and the likelihood of collisions, my question was more along the line of "Do they select within age groups at certain times?" (seems unlikely, but plausible), "Do they do the selection in bulk a month before?" Just general facts about how the selection process works.

Comment: The electoral register should be able to tell you how they select, re: by age group, when and how. It won't be a secret, or shoiuldn't be.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch If you wear your tin foil hat to court, nobody will want you on their jury.